# PHP/mysql:Rank users by clicks

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

So i want to rank users by clicks here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User ranking</title>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>User</th> 
    <th>clicks</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>

    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "...";
    $password = "...";
    $dbname = "...";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  id, user FROM users";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["user"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But here is my problem:The "users" column has duplicate users, In the table i want to count only Unique users as "Users" AND you noticed i haven't mention "clicks" in the php code because i don't have clicks column in the database...

So here is how i want to count clicks: As i said the "users" column has duplicate users i want to count how many times a username has duplicated and rank them.

For example:
User John X3 and Dan X2 is in the database
i want to count how many times John and Dan duplicated because John is 3 times John is ranked #1 and Dan should be #2

Also here is another problem:
The database resets every 24 hours so all data is gone every 24 hours.
How to solve that?how to permanently display database data, I mean display database data and then after 24 hours keep it increasing...

I don't know if this is useful or not: the database has "Id" column and it doesn't reset
for example 3 times John is in the database, 'John with id 1' 'john with id 2' and 'john with id 3'.

No problem if JS has been used.
Btw i'm a beginner i tried to do that...i spent about 7 hours but every try was  failed.

Thanks for answering

Comment: Please open multiple seperate questions if you have multiple questions ;) Additionally, if the database is reset every 24 hours and that is a problem, just don't do that

Comment: @NicoHaase okay thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So here is how i want to count clicks: As i said the "users" column has duplicate users i want to count how many times a username has duplicated and rank them.

You want aggregation:

```
select user, count(*) clicks from users group by user order by clicks desc
```